# define the UITableViewCell out of Storyboard with NIB

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, ios7, nib

I used the Json array to show data from server.

when I change the CellIdentifier to @Cell which i used in CellIdentifier the pushDetailView is working and it's going to next page but when I change to CustomCell again just show the name of city and state in first page and when i click on that doesnt go to next page. the reason I need the @CustomCell because I need 2 labels view in first page and when I change it to @cell it just show one label.

Thank you.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (!cell)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell...

City * cityObject;
cityObject = [ citiesArry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = cityObject.cityState;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = cityObject.cityPopulation;


cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 4;


//NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mobileapps.binaryappdev.com/applelogo.png"]  ];

//[[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]  ];


return cell;
}


#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a story board-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{


if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"pushDetailView"])

{

    NSIndexPath * indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    City * object = [citiesArry objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

    [[segue destinationViewController] getCity:object];
}
}



#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Class Methods


-(void) retrievedData;

{
NSURL * URL = [ NSURL URLWithString:getDataURL];
NSData * data = [ NSData  dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];

jsonArry = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:Nil];


//city


citiesArry = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//loop

for (int i=0; i<jsonArry.count; i++) {

    NSString * cID = [[ jsonArry objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"];
    NSString * cName = [[ jsonArry objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"cityName"];
    NSString * cState = [[ jsonArry objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"cityState"];
    NSString * cCountry = [[ jsonArry objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"country"];
    NSString * cPopulation = [[ jsonArry objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"cityPopulation"];
    NSString * cImage = [[ jsonArry objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"cityImage"];




    [citiesArry addObject:[[City alloc] initWithcityName:cName andcityState:cState andcityCountry:cCountry andcityPopulation:cPopulation andcityImage:cImage andcityID:cID ]];




     }

     [self.tableView reloadData];

}

@end
```

DetailViewController

```
@synthesize cityNameLabel, stateLabel, countryLabel, populationLabel, currentCity;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.



[self setLabels];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}




#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Class Methods



-(void) getCity:(id)cityObject


{


currentCity = cityObject;

}


-(void) setLabels

{

cityNameLabel.text= currentCity.cityName;
countryLabel.text = currentCity.cityCountry;
stateLabel.text = currentCity.cityState;
populationLabel.text = currentCity.cityPopulation;
cityNameLabel.numberOfLines= 0;

}



@end
```

Comment: Show the code which is fired when user taps on the cell.

Comment: @reecon  you mean detailview class?

Comment: the cell identifier is the string that you set in storyboard for your cell, so it will load the cell that contains it. For custom cells, you have to subclass them and add your own labels or whatever else you need.

Comment: @CalinChitu thanks for ur comment, can you give me the sample code how to do that? create the subclass for CustomCell and add that to Cell?

Answer (score 0):

if you don´t have segue for your customcell when you push in a cell your method didSelectRow:AtIndexPath will be called. You can do yourself a pushViewController from that method or [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"pushDetailView" sender: self];

Comment: Thank you for your comment. yeah right, but when I add this code to the app the first page changed to detailview page and then when I tried  tap to back to first page again same result in first page and i can not back to detail view